# Browser cannot load html offline

Tags: html

I saved some webpages for offline viewing. When I try to open the files  the browser pops up with the message: cannot load htlm offline. Firefox can’t find the file at /home/user/......mhtml. Have also tried using another browser and receive a similar message.

I never used to get this problem. Is there a solution?

Comment: I saved the webpage as a single MHTML file into my home directory. As the owner I assume to have permission? Opening with Firefox or Web.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla Firefox does not support MHTML.
Since version 57 ("Firefox Quantum"), MHT files can no longer be read and written.
In previous versions this was possible by installing some browser extensions such as
Mozilla Archive Format or UnMHT, but they are no longer compatible with the
latest Firefox versions.

Internet Explorer is currently the only modern browser that still supports that format.

EDIT : Chrome opens MHTML.

Comment: Are there any Linux browsers reading MHT?

Comment: Found just now that Chrome does it.